# button to dynamically load $body data into <textarea>

Tags: php, javascript

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <textarea name="list" id="emails" rows="10" value="Send to" ondblclick="select_all('emails');" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Send to' || this.value == 'Send to: separate emails by comma and space') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Send to: separate emails by comma and space';}" cols="40">Send to</textarea><br/>
    <input name="subject" id="subject" value="Subject" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Subject') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your JaGex Account';}" size="17"/>
    <select name="template" id="template" onchange="load();">
        <option value="none">Don't use template</option>
        <option value="RWT">Report Abuse</option>
        <option value="renew">Resend Email Codes</option>
    </select>
    <button name="load" type="submit" id="bt3" onclick="load();" style="width: 50px;"><span>Load</span></button><br/>
    <textarea name="body" rows="10" id="content" ondblclick="select_all('content');" cols="40"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($body)?></textarea><br/>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="bt1" onclick="disable();" style="width: 345px;"><span>Send</span></button>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="bt2" style="visibility:hidden;width: 345px;"><span>Sending...</span>
    </button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function load() { 
    document.form1.submit(); 
}
</script>
```

When I click load it doesn't load any option data into the textarea.

```
else if ($template == "RWT") {
        $body = "Dear Player,<br/><br/>";
        $body .= "We regret to inform you that your account has received an infraction due to a Major offense. Please visit the appeal section under Account Management to view evidence of your infraction(s) and to appeal any infraction(s) that you feel were unjustified.<br/><br/>";
```

How do I get the data to post inside the textarea?

Comment: Where's the `<form>` ? And you're just submitting it?  Shouldn't there be an ajax call or something?

Comment: @Pointy: Just submitting it is fine. AJAX would just make it smoother.

Comment: Is `$template` assigned like this `$template=$_POST['template']`?

Comment: @Kyle: Your code is incomplete so we can't really tell. You say "it doesn't load any option data", but what _does_ happen? Does the page refresh at all? Put some debugging lines in your PHP and check for errors in your Javascript console and tell us what you get. I suspect it's because you're using the invalid `document.form1.submit()` syntax popularised by IE6.

Comment: I notice your using `<?php echo(variable); ?>`. I recently learned that you can use the equivalent `<?= variable ?>` and it caused me much joy for the 7 spared characters :)

Comment: @Pointy It is just submitting the form I don't really understand ajax very well

@Shakti Singh yes

@Tomalak Geret'kal it just doesn't post the data inside the <textarea> It does however when I send the form but I don't want it to send the form:| I just want it to load the data so I can get it ready to send.

Comment: @Kyle your form is missing an action attribute.

Comment: @Kyle nice name. I'll see if that helps lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**php**

```
 // have you written this like before else
        $template=$_POST['template'];

    else if ($template == "RWT") {
```

**javascript**

```
 function load()
   {
    document.forms["Your_form"].submit();
   }
```

Comment: I tried your new JS function but it still doesn't post the data to the textarea. :|

Comment: are you looking for full page post back request or ajax request!!